# Executing last action when back button pressed ASP.Net

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a ListBox with a "list of servers" that has AutoPostBack enabled and an SelectedIndexChanged event attached to it:

```
    protected void lbServerList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if ( lbServerList.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")
        {
            Response.Redirect("detail.aspx?Server=" +  lbServerList.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then I have a textbox to add a "server" with a button "btnServertoAdd" (to execute the addition)

```
    protected void btnServertoAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("add.aspx?Server=" + tbServertoAdd.Text);
    }
```

Scenario: If I select an item from the ListBox it will go to detail.aspx showing the server specs: Awesome.
Now, If I click back (browser button) and then type something in the TextBox and click btnServerToAdd it will still go to detail.aspx and not to add.aspx as it should....
How can I fix this?

Let me know if more code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because when you click the button, the selected server is also different from the original value (as stored in the view state). Both events are fired, but evidently the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired first and the `Redirect` skips the rest of the processing.

I can't think of how to *not* make the `SelectedIndexChanged` event fire the second time around, so instead what you could do is, instead of `Redirect`ing in the events themselves:

1. Have a pair of `bool` member variables in your page class.
2. Set one to `true` in each event handler.
3. In the page `OnLoadComplete` event, check each and redirect as necessary:

   - If *both* are `true`, redirect to `add.aspx`.
   - If one is `true`, redirect to the corresponding page.
   - Otherwise don't redirect at all.

Comment: But events are processed after Load.

Comment: PreRender then. You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, maybe I don't know deep enough c#. I added the bool member variables, however every time the page Loaded they were reset back. I used ViewState but I had to perform twice the action for the page to go where I wanted.

Comment: No, the idea is that they are `false` at the start of every page load. You can then see which of the two events have fired _on that pageload_ and decide were, if anywhere, to redirect, rather than redirecting as soon as either event occurs.